# ImageMagick Identify fails for tiff files

Tags: windows, imagemagick, imagemagick-convert, imagemagick-identify

I am using "identify" method of ImageMagick to get size of images. I use command in format:

```
"identify.exe" -format "%wx%h" "[IMAGE_FILE_PATH]"
```

I am unable to get resolution of few images. Want to know if this could be an issue with image? Or something missing in command?

Image 1 Error :

```
identify.exe: Incompatible type for "RichTIFFIPTC"; tag ignored. `TIFFFetchNormalTag' @ warning/tiff.c/TIFFWarnings/1029.
```

Image 2 Error :

```
ERROR :identify.exe: Unknown field with tag 34016 (0x84e0) encountered. `TIFFReadDirectory' @ warning/tiff.c/TIFFWarnings/1029.
identify.exe: Unknown field with tag 34017 (0x84e1) encountered. `TIFFReadDirectory' @ warning/tiff.c/TIFFWarnings/1029.
identify.exe: Unknown field with tag 34018 (0x84e2) encountered. `TIFFReadDirectory' @ warning/tiff.c/TIFFWarnings/1029.
identify.exe: Unknown field with tag 34019 (0x84e3) encountered. `TIFFReadDirectory' @ warning/tiff.c/TIFFWarnings/1029.
identify.exe: Unknown field with tag 34020 (0x84e4) encountered. `TIFFReadDirectory' @ warning/tiff.c/TIFFWarnings/1029.
identify.exe: Unknown field with tag 34021 (0x84e5) encountered. `TIFFReadDirectory' @ warning/tiff.c/TIFFWarnings/1029.
identify.exe: Unknown field with tag 34022 (0x84e6) encountered. `TIFFReadDirectory' @ warning/tiff.c/TIFFWarnings/1029.
identify.exe: Unknown field with tag 34023 (0x84e7) encountered. `TIFFReadDirectory' @ warning/tiff.c/TIFFWarnings/1029.
identify.exe: Unknown field with tag 34024 (0x84e8) encountered. `TIFFReadDirectory' @ warning/tiff.c/TIFFWarnings/1029.
identify.exe: Unknown field with tag 34025 (0x84e9) encountered. `TIFFReadDirectory' @ warning/tiff.c/TIFFWarnings/1029.
identify.exe: Unknown field with tag 34026 (0x84ea) encountered. `TIFFReadDirectory' @ warning/tiff.c/TIFFWarnings/1029.
identify.exe: Unknown field with tag 34027 (0x84eb) encountered. `TIFFReadDirectory' @ warning/tiff.c/TIFFWarnings/1029.
identify.exe: Unknown field with tag 34028 (0x84ec) encountered. `TIFFReadDirectory' @ warning/tiff.c/TIFFWarnings/1029.
identify.exe: Unknown field with tag 34029 (0x84ed) encountered. `TIFFReadDirectory' @ warning/tiff.c/TIFFWarnings/1029.
identify.exe: Unknown field with tag 34030 (0x84ee) encountered. `TIFFReadDirectory' @ warning/tiff.c/TIFFWarnings/1029.
identify.exe: C:\.FieryJobFlow/5378/JF1130329232719937_.tif: Null count for "Tag 34022" (type 1, writecount -3, passcount 1). `_TIFFVSetField' @ error/tiff.c/TIFFErrors/665.
identify.exe: C:\.FieryJobFlow/5378/JF1130329232719937_.tif: Null count for "Tag 34025" (type 1, writecount -3, passcount 1). `_TIFFVSetField' @ error/tiff.c/TIFFErrors/665.
identify.exe: C:\.FieryJobFlow/5378/JF1130329232719937_.tif: Null count for "Tag 34026" (type 1, writecount -3, passcount 1). `_TIFFVSetField' @ error/tiff.c/TIFFErrors/665.
```

ImageMagick version:

```
Version: ImageMagick 7.0.9-14 Q16 x86 2020-01-05 http://www.imagemagick.org
Copyright: Copyright (C) 1999-2018 ImageMagick Studio LLC
License: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Visual C++: 180040629
Features: Cipher DPC HDRI OpenCL
Delegates (built-in): bzlib cairo flif freetype gslib heic jng jp2 jpeg lcms lqr lzma openexr pangocairo png ps raw rsvg tiff webp xml zlib
```

One more thing I noticed is, convert.exe from ImageMagick is processing fine for Image1 but not for Image2.

Is there any way to know if there is some issue with image?

Thanks.

Comment: All of the messages are warnings that the tiff file has tags that Imagemagick does not know, except for the last 3. Those are errors, which likely means the file is corrupt or malformed.  Can you post an example TIFF?  What is our IM version and platform and version of libtiff?

Comment: Thanks for the explanation. 
Is there a way to supress the warning and get output in stdout instead of stderr? 
Image one with warning is more than 50 MB. OS is windows 10. 
IM Version: 
ImageMagick 7.0.9-14 Q16 x86 2020-01-05 http://www.imagemagick.org
License: http://www.imagemagick.org/script/license.php
Visual C++: 180040629
Features: Cipher DPC HDRI OpenCL
Delegates (built-in): bzlib cairo flif freetype gslib heic jng jp2 jpeg lcms lqr lzma openexr pangocairo png ps raw rsvg tiff webp xml zlib

Comment: You can suppress warnings by adding -quiet after convert in your command line. Redirect your command using 2>&1. See https://linuxize.com/post/bash-redirect-stderr-stdout/